# How can I get the value of a variable from another file into the function php?

Tags: php, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have a Joomla module
In the **Default.php** file, a function is called and a variable from the **xml file**.
But it does not find variable function.
**$mod_circle_display1** Not read by function ;
And the function directly sees the **else**, and the output of the function is **column1** ( that's mean :$mod_circle_displayres3 ).

My Default.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/function.php';
$check = CheckDisplay();
 ?>

 <div class="<?php echo CheckDisplay()?> <?php echo $mod_circle_move1;?>"
 style="<?php echo $mod_circle_display1;?>">

 <div class="<?php echo CheckDisplay()?> <?php echo $mod_circle_move2;?>"
 style="<?php echo $mod_circle_display2;?>">

 <div class="<?php echo CheckDisplay()?> <?php echo $mod_circle_move3;?>"
 style="<?php echo $mod_circle_display3;?>">

 <div class="<?php echo CheckDisplay()?> <?php echo $mod_circle_move4;?>"
 style="<?php echo $mod_circle_display4;?>">
```

My Function.php

```
         function CheckDisplay ()
{ 
       /*global $mod_circle_display1; is not worked*/
       /*global $mod_circle_display2; is not worked*/
       /*global $mod_circle_display3; is not worked*/
       /*global $mod_circle_display4; is not worked*/
        $mod_circle_display1;
        $mod_circle_display2;
        $mod_circle_display3;
        $mod_circle_display4;

        $mod_circle_displayon = "display:none !important";
        $mod_circle_displayoff = "padding:0";

        $mod_circle_displayres1 = "column4";
        $mod_circle_displayres2 = "column2";
        $mod_circle_displayres3 = "column1";

     if (($mod_circle_display1 == $mod_circle_displayoff)AND($mod_circle_display2 == $mod_circle_displayoff)AND
         ($mod_circle_display3 == $mod_circle_displayoff)AND($mod_circle_display4 == $mod_circle_displayoff))
        {
           return $mod_circle_displayres1;
        }
 elseif (($mod_circle_display1 == $mod_circle_displayoff)AND($mod_circle_display2 == $mod_circle_displayon)AND
         ($mod_circle_display3 == $mod_circle_displayoff)AND($mod_circle_display4 == $mod_circle_displayon))
        {
           return $mod_circle_displayres2;
        }
  else { return $mod_circle_displayres3; }
```

My mod_circle.xml

```
<field name="mod_circle_display1"
 type="list" 
 default="padding:0" 
 label="MOD_CIRCLE_DISPLAY1" 
 description="MOD_CIRCLE_DISPLAY1">
 <option value="display:none !important">Yes</option>
 <option value="padding:0">No</option>
</field>
and ...
```

My mod_circle.php

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

require_once __DIR__ . '/helper.php';

$mod_circle_background          = $params->get('mod_circle_background');
$mod_circle_widthrl             = $params->get('mod_circle_widthrl');
$mod_circle_display1            = $params->get('mod_circle_display1');
$mod_circle_image1              = $params->get('mod_circle_image1');
$mod_circle_opacity1            = $params->get('mod_circle_opacity1');
$mod_circle_width1              = $params->get('mod_circle_width1');
$mod_circle_height1             = $params->get('mod_circle_height1');
$mod_circle_margin1             = $params->get('mod_circle_margin1');
$mod_circle_radius1             = $params->get('mod_circle_radius1');
$mod_circle_circle1             = $params->get('mod_circle_circle1');
$mod_circle_circletime1         = $params->get('mod_circle_circletime1');
and
    $mod_circle_display2            = $params->get('mod_circle_display2');
Etc.
    $mod_circle_display3            = $params->get('mod_circle_display3');
Etc.
    $mod_circle_display4            = $params->get('mod_circle_display4');
Etc.
```

Comment: When you need Joomla-specific support, please post your question at Joomla Stack Exchange to reach a dedicated support audience.  Team Joomla wants you to post there -- that's why in the adminstrator -> Help menua, the 2nd last item in the dropdown says **Stack Exchange**.

Answer (score 1):

First you got to underrate that as far as your PHP script is concern, $mod_circle_display1 does not exist.

It may exist (so to say) in XML but not in your PHP

You will need to parse the required value from the XML file into a php variable ($mod_circle_display1) first and then make $mod_circle_display1 a global variable (see this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp)

You can even read the XML file into $mod_circle_display1 from inside your function so you wont need to make $mod_circle_display1 a global variable

Comment: In the mod_circle.php file, all xmls are called,
I added the mod_circle.php file in my question.

Comment: I still can't seem to find where you parsed the xml in your code. The only way you can read those information from the xml is by parsing it using something like php_xml_simplexml_read() as described in the link I gave you